# Can you have more than one transport client in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-boot, hbase

So I have a Spring Boot application. I've been using it with ElasticSearch. Now I have added an HBase connection. They use transport protocols, I believe TCP clients to connect and communicate.

However, I am now getting some sort of lifecycle error in Spring Boot. I'm wondering if this means that having more than one connection like this (kinda like a socket) means that they need to be in their own threads somehow? I thought Spring Boot would automatically handle that in a way.

```
@PostConstruct
```

Do I need them in their own threads? Should I separate them into different Java Apps?

If I separate them, wouldn't I need to find a way to record things in both? How would they communicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, turns out the problems I face are when there are netty conflicts. Once netty conflicts in POM.xml are resolved, it can multi-thread connect using Spring Boot to different servers.

Comment: Can i have different transport client for same elastic server ?